# Removal of unused dependencies using "autoremove"

Tags: apt

I thought running `apt-get autoremove` without any following argument removes all unused dependencies left on the system, while running `apt-get autoremove xxx` removes xxx and its unused dependencies.

However I discovered otherwise. Running `apt-get autoremove xxx` not only removes xxx and its unused dependencies, it also removes all other unused dependencies.

I then tried running `apt-get remove --auto-remove xxx`, thinking that this would remove only xxx and its unused dependencies. To my surprise, this also removed xxx, its unused dependencies, and all other unused dependencies.

This leads me to two related questions.

(1) Is this the intended behaviour of the commands?

(2) Is there an easy way to remove xxx and its unused dependencies without removing other unused dependencies?

(It appears that `aptitude remove` also behaves in a similar way.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking in the file `cmdline/apt-get.cc` from the source tarball at http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/maverick/apt, I can see that `--auto-remove` is an argument which enables the `APT::Get::AutomaticRemove` setting.

The commands `autoremove` and `remove` both calls the function `DoInstall`.

The command "autoremove" sets `APT::Get::AutomaticRemove` too and it does therefore the same thing as `--auto-remove`.

Looking in the `DoAutomaticRemove` function, it's clearly visible that enabling the `APT::Get::AutomaticRemove` setting (`--auto-remove` and `autoremove` does this) causes Apt looping through all installed packages and marks unused packages for deletion.

From `main()`:

```
CommandLine::Args Args[] = {
   // ... stripped to save space
   {0,"auto-remove","APT::Get::AutomaticRemove",0},
   // ...
}
CommandLine::Dispatch Cmds[] = { // ...
                                {"remove",&DoInstall},
                                {"purge",&DoInstall},
                                {"autoremove",&DoInstall},
                                // ...
}
// ...
// Parse the command line and initialize the package library
CommandLine CmdL(Args,_config);
```

From `DoInstall()`:

```
 unsigned short fallback = MOD_INSTALL;
   if (strcasecmp(CmdL.FileList[0],"remove") == 0)
      fallback = MOD_REMOVE;
   else if (strcasecmp(CmdL.FileList[0], "purge") == 0)
   {
      _config->Set("APT::Get::Purge", true);
      fallback = MOD_REMOVE;
   }
   else if (strcasecmp(CmdL.FileList[0], "autoremove") == 0)
   {
      _config->Set("APT::Get::AutomaticRemove", "true");
      fallback = MOD_REMOVE;
   }
```

From function `DoAutomaticRemove`:

```
   bool doAutoRemove = _config->FindB("APT::Get::AutomaticRemove", false);
   // ...
   // look over the cache to see what can be removed
   for (pkgCache::PkgIterator Pkg = Cache->PkgBegin(); ! Pkg.end(); ++Pkg) {
       if (doAutoRemove) {
       if(Pkg.CurrentVer() != 0 && 
          Pkg->CurrentState != pkgCache::State::ConfigFiles)
          Cache->MarkDelete(Pkg, purgePkgs);
       else
          Cache->MarkKeep(Pkg, false, false);
   }
   }
```

I cannot speak whether it's intended or not, you could fill [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt) / ask [a question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt) at [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt).

---

At the moment, it is not possible to exclude packages from deletion by `apt-get autoremove`. If you want to keep packages, run `apt-get -s autoremove`, copy the packages from the list and remove the packages from that list you want to keep. Finally, remove those packages: `sudo apt-get purge [packages-to-be-removed]` (purge removes the configuration files too, if any)

Comment: What do you recommend to remove just xxx and its unused dependencies then? Please include that in the answer for my learning, thanks!

Comment: You cannot exclude packages from autoremove, if you want to keep packages from being auto-removed, remove them with `apt-get purge` or `apt-get remove`.